# Nav link menu linking to a section in the same page

Tags: html

I am working on my first html web code. How do I link the nav link menus to the section containing the real text within the same page.

I used `<a href="#about.html">About</a>` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the id selector `href="#idOfTargetedElement"`, see example below :

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#about">About</a>
<h1 id="about">About</h1>
```